# iOS image processing software auto crop to borders

Tags: ios, image-editing

I am implementing an application and my app needs to crop image based on background contrast. I have seen similar behavior in document scanning applications where they automatically pick up image borders for crop. Can someone help me figure out how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: This sounds like a programming question, and most likely belongs in StackOverflow, not here.

Comment: I'm going to close this to see if we can edit it into shape. If it's about programming a scanner - it's certainly off topic unless that programming will be exclusively in AppleScript or Automator. If you're looking to use existing software to automate this, then let's edit and flag this for reopening. That's clearly on-topic here. So it's too vague to know how to answer or whether it's really on topic or not at present.